# How to align the coordinate system of CMAttitude and that of ARKit?

Tags: arkit, core-motion, coordinate-transformation

We have the rotation matrixs got from the [CMAttitude](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmattitude?language=objc) (Core motion framework) in the [CMAttitudeReferenceFrameXArbitraryZVertical](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmattitudereferenceframe/cmattitudereferenceframexarbitraryzvertical?language=objc) reference frame, and the rotation matrixs got from the [arkit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit?language=objc) in the [ARWorldAlignmentGravity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldalignment/arworldalignmentgravity?language=objc) reference frame.

How to align the coordinate system of CMAttitude and that of ARKit?